# Problems with using Riffle, Grid and TableForm

Tags: list-manipulation, grid-layouts, output-formatting

I have the following `Table`:

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
Module[{startX = 10, endX = 12, endJ = 5},
  table1 = Table["", {j, 1, endJ}]; 
  table2 = Table[x/j, {x, startX, endX}, {j, 1, endJ}]; 
  table3 = Table[j/x, {x, startX, endX}, {j, 1, endJ}]; 
  table4 = Table[N[Sqrt[x]/j^2 - j^2/x], {x, startX, endX}, {j, 1, endJ}]; 
  table5 = Riffle[table2, table3]; 
  table6 = Riffle[table5, table4, 3]; 
  table7 = Riffle[table6, table1, 4];]
```

The idea is that there are four consecutive rows for each value `x`, each displaying the relevant values from `table1`, `table2`, `table3` and `table4`. But I have a few problems:

1. `table7` is missing its last line - here's a screenshot:

[image]

2. `TableForm[table7]` displays correctly, but

   ```
    TableForm [table7, 
      TableHeadings -> 
        {{"x=1", "", "", "", "2", "", "", "", "3", "", "", ""}, 
         {"j=1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}}]
   ```

   does not — there are no dividers.
3. Although `TableForm[table7]` works, `Grid [table7]` does not. (**Update: @kglr has solved this issue in the comments below**)

Can anyone help me fix these issues?

Ideally, I would prefer a solution using `Grid` since this allows more flexibility with dividers.

Comment: for problem 3: replace `""` in `table7` with `{""}`; that is, use `Grid[table7 /. "" -> {""}]`.

Comment: Many thanks @kglr

Comment: Your 1st question is weird. There is no `table6` used in the definition of `table5`. Is that a typo or did I miss something?

Comment: Hi @halirutan. Question amended and clarified. Thanks for the heads-up.